# How to extract specific data from a string of text

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use JavaScript to remove unwanted data.  For example in this address:

```
url("assets/images/films/deor/films_deor_ip_full_1.jpg")
```

I want to create a variable with only the "1" as the value.

Its used for a picture viewer, scrolling to the next image.  So the entire string always stays the same except for the number.  I want to be able to grab that number anytime and place in a variable.

Comment: You could try `parseInt` of a `substr` of that string. Or use a regex: `/_full_(\d+).match(theString) [1];`.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on that, sorry i am new to this.

Comment: You said that the strings are all alike except for the numbers. So then you could cut the strings right after the `_` before the numbers (which after 49 characters) and then use `parseInt to get the number: `var number = parseInt(theString.substr(49));`.

Comment: Or better, just use a regex like this: `var number = /_full_(\d+).match(theString) [1];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression to extract the number, for example:

```
var url = "assets/images/films/deor/films_deor_ip_full_1.jpg";
var regex = /_(\d+)\.jpg$/i;
var imgNumber = parseInt(regex.exec(url)[1], 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to strip the unwanted data away, but rather retrieve the *wanted* data. You can do this because you know at what index the integer will occur.

Here's an example:

```
let startIdx = "assets/images/films/deor/films_deor_ip_full_".length();
let endIdx = str.length()-".jpg".length();
let theInt = parseInt(str.substring(startIdx, endIdx));
```

*Sidenote:*

> I want to be able to grab that number anytime and place in a variable.

Concerning the second part, in JavaScript, strings are immutable, meaning you cannot change them after you create them.